C# WPF MVVM - AutoCompleteBox only triggers on first Character
I got this C# WPF Application with MVVM framework and I wanted to create an AutoCompleteBox using
clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls;assembly=DotNetProjects.Input.Toolkit
The DataContext is set like this in the XAML
DataContext="{x:Static local:OverledeneViewModel.Instance}"
and this is the AutoCompleteBox
            <input:AutoCompleteBox
            x:Name="autoCompleteBox"
            ItemsSource="{Binding FilteredSuggestions}"
            Text="{Binding SearchText, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
            SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedLocatie}"
            FilterMode="ContainsOrdinal"
            MinimumPrefixLength="1"
            VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
            HorizontalAlignment="Left"
            Margin="783,158,0,0"
            Width="336"
            Height="32"
            FontSize="16"
            FontFamily="Arial" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                <input:AutoCompleteBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding LongName}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </input:AutoCompleteBox.ItemTemplate>
            </input:AutoCompleteBox>

in the viewmodel there is this
        private ObservableCollection<SuggestionModel> _filteredSuggestions;
        private ObservableCollection<SuggestionModel> _locatieSuggestions;

        private SuggestionModel? _selectedLocatie;
        private string? _searchText;

        public string? SearchText
        {
            get => _searchText;
            set
            {
                if (_searchText != value)
                {
                    _searchText = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged(nameof(SearchText));
                    UpdateFilteredSuggestions();
                }
            }
        }

        public SuggestionModel? SelectedLocatie
        {
            get => _selectedLocatie;
            set
            {
                if (_selectedLocatie != value)
                {
                    _selectedLocatie = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged(nameof(SelectedLocatie));
                }
            }
        }
        public ObservableCollection<SuggestionModel> FilteredSuggestions
        {
            get { return _filteredSuggestions; }
            set { _filteredSuggestions = value; OnPropertyChanged(nameof(FilteredSuggestions)); }
        }
        public ObservableCollection<SuggestionModel> LocatieSuggestions
        {
            get { return _locatieSuggestions; }
            set { _locatieSuggestions = value; OnPropertyChanged(nameof(LocatieSuggestions)); }
        }

        private OverledeneViewModel()
        {
            LoadSuggestions();
        }

        private void LoadSuggestions()
        {
            var suggestions = miscellaneousRepository.GetSuggestions();
            LocatieSuggestions.Clear();
            foreach (var suggestion in suggestions)
            {
                LocatieSuggestions.Add(suggestion);
            }
            UpdateFilteredSuggestions();
        }
        private void UpdateFilteredSuggestions()
        {
            System.Windows.Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
            {
                //FilteredSuggestions.Clear();

                var filtered = LocatieSuggestions
                    .Where(s =>
                        (s.LongName != null && s.LongName.Contains(SearchText ?? string.Empty, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) ||
                        (s.ShortName != null && s.ShortName.Contains(SearchText ?? string.Empty, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)))
                    .ToList();

                Debug.WriteLine($"Filtered count: {filtered.Count}");
                foreach (var item in filtered)
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine(item.LongName); // Log to debug output
                    FilteredSuggestions.Add(item);
                }
            });
        }

and this is the part thats retrieving the data from the database
public IEnumerable<SuggestionModel> GetSuggestions()
{
    var suggestions = new List<SuggestionModel>();

    using (var connection = GetConnection())
    using (var command = new SqlCommand())
    {
        connection.Open();
        command.Connection = connection;
        command.CommandText = "SELECT [Id],[ShortName],[LongName],[Street],[Housenumber],[Zipcode],[City],[IsActive] " +
                                "FROM [EeftingDossierRegistratie].[dbo].[ConfigurationOverledenLocaties] ";

        using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                if ((bool)reader["IsActive"] == true)
                {
                    suggestions.Add(new SuggestionModel
                    {
                        Id = (Guid)reader["Id"],
                        ShortName = reader["ShortName"].ToString(),
                        LongName = reader["LongName"].ToString(),
                        Street = reader["Street"].ToString(),
                        HouseNumber = reader["HouseNumber"].ToString(),
                        ZipCode = reader["ZipCode"].ToString(),
                        City = reader["City"].ToString(),
                        IsActive = reader["IsActive"] as bool?
                    });
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return suggestions;
}

this is data that the database will return
| Id                                    | ShortName | LongName                                 | Street   | HouseNumber | ZipCode | City      | IsActive |
| ------------------------------------- | --------- | ---------------------------------------- | -------- | ----------- | ------- | --------- | -------- |
| 98ED4412-7026-4C78-8537-1943844CF533 | UMCG      | Universitair Medisch Centrum Groningen   | Street1  | 1           | 1234 AA | Groningen | 1        |
| 2E527E4A-36A5-48A4-A34C-8DA5F5B84E4A |           | Spaarne Gasthuis                         | Street2  | 2a          | 4321 BB | Harlingen | 1        |
When I run the tool and I type in the AutoCompleteBox the letter u it show's both in the suggestion but when I add the m so the search criterea becomes um it's not showing any suggestions anymore while in the debug.writeline i see this
Filtered count: 1
Universitair Medisch Centrum Groningen
So how come it's not showing any results? what am I doing wrong?
Hope you can help me out.
Patrick

What happens when you type "un"? (Fuzzy searching is different from incremental searching)
